# Get actual href value from a html in c#

Tags: c#, jquery, html

I want to get the actual href value, which actually differs from what is being shown in inspect element in a browser. 
For more clarity, if I go to this (http://185.105.101.95/S/Money.Heist/S01/720p.x264.WEB-DL/) page and inspect html content then for the first href tag the value is "/S/Money.Heist/S01/" but when I click on the link, it directs to "http://185.105.101.95/S/Money.Heist/S01/". So my question is how I can get the actual href value using html elements and c#. Or by using jquery.
Thanks for helping

Comment: I am extracting html content from an uri in c# using htmlContent = webClient.DownloadString(uri);

Comment: And then I am trying to extract all href element values from the htmlcontent

Comment: Will it be correct to rephrase the question to " How am I able to get the full href url from relative url in href?"